# Why are position markers, like first or last, in an Enumeration considered bad practice?

Tags: c#, enumeration

According to the Best Practices section of the MSDN documentation for the System.Enum class:

> Do not define an enumeration value solely to mirror the state of the enumeration itself. For example, do not define an enumerated constant that merely marks the end of the enumeration. If you need to determine the last value of the enumeration, check for that value explicitly. In addition, you can perform a range check for the first and last enumerated constant if all values within the range are valid.

If I understand correctly, we shouldn't declare an enum as follows.

```
public enum DrawOrder
{
    VeryBottom = 0,
    Bottom = 1,
    Middle = 2,
    Top = 3,
    Lowest = VeryBottom, //marks a position in the enum
    Highest = Top, //marks a position in the enum
}
```

Why is this considered bad practice?

Comment: I guess this is a practice carried over from C/C++. In the .NET world, we have `Enum.IsDefined`, `Enum.GetValues`, etc. so the hack doesn't make much sense any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because those values may change over time. Suppose you set a property to (using your example) `DrawOrder.Highest` and store it in your database/document/other-data-sink.

Time passes.

Code Changes.

Your `DrawOrder` enum has acquired a few more values and the value in your persisted data is now no longer equal to `DrawOrder.Highest`. It's only equal to what ever `DrawOrder.Highest` mapped to at the time the data was persisted.

Do you think that this situation might have the possibility of causing problems?

Comment: I like this explanation the best, even though all the answers are similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I agree that it's bad practice; it depends.

Steve McConnell's *Code Complete* uses this construct.  (This book is starting to show its age with the languages it uses, so this technique may have been *good* practice then.)

The downside is that there's an extra thing to remember to do if you update the enumeration list: update the value of `Highest` and/or `Lowest`, if needed.  If you forget, you'll introduce bugs.

The upside is that the code you write for loops is faster and self-documenting.

Answer (score 2):

Because if you add `VeryTop = 4` to the enumeration, you have to remember to update `Highest`.

If you fail to do so, all hell breaks loose. It's surprisingly easy to forget about that after some time (a few months) has passed.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's only a bad idea if you are persisting the Enum and there is a chance the enum may change.  If you are not persisting it, or there is no chance of the enum changing, then it's probably fine in most cases.  But then the whole point of a marker is because the value may change... so it doesn't really make any sense.

However, one needs to be careful when using such a construct that they use the enumeration they actually intend.  If you mean Top, but use Highest instead... and then later add SuperTop and change Highest to that, then your original intention may now be a bug.

The Marker enum should only be used when you want to use whatever the highest or lowest is, regardless of its value.

So many people consider it bad practice because it's really easy to use a marker when you intend a specific value.